# It's not the cats fault it's mine

Tags: cats, training, defecation, feral

So I got a cat about 2 months ago. They were not specific of the age as they found her outside fairly young. I don't think they had her long, I'd imagine she's like 5 months old now. She's great with us minus the whole must sniff hand thoroughly before petting.

The question is what else can I do to convince her the lottery box is the place to go?
This is what I've tried so far. 
Can't seem to get her to poop in the litter box though. Everyone says it's all about the box. So I have 2. They all have an unscented litter because I've found she'll pee on that, but hates scents. Both boxes are in Her room. Her food is opposite side of her room. We leave her in her room at night because that's when she poops at like 3 am to 5 am I can't always be up at that time. The internet says putting her in a room with less options would encourage her.

When she poops on the carpet and it's still fresh I pick up the cat and with toilet paper pick up the poop, put it in the litter box, then set her next to the litter box, (she's offended if I put her in it).
I've been trying for awhile now and the next step is to add catnip to the litter. I'm kinda broke right now but I'm going to try and get go here litter soon.
I've also thought about putting chili powder down where she's been point most recently. I normally move the boxes to where she pooped last after cleaning it, but she'll just poop on the other side of the room.

Comment: There are many similar questions that already have an answer. Have a look at: [How can stop my adult cat from urinating in inappropriate places?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1009/12501), [How can I get my cat to stop pooping on the bed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6773/12501), [How can I indicate where my kitten is supposed to do her business?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1488/12501), [Cat: Sanitary Issues and Peeing Outside The Box](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/20572/12501)

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome to pets.

The best thing to do is to take the lid off of the litter box and take your cat and put her in the litter tray and show her how to dig,take her paw and use it to dig in the litter if she resist use your own hand and show her how to do this.

You might have to do this a couple of times.Do not put the lid on the litter box until she starts to use it correctly teaching a cat can take a little time but when she understands she will remember this forever.

This answer is a bit short but we have several simmilar questions on our site and i think this one will be closed as a duplicate.